# How to connect remotely to Mongodb running on Docker-compose?

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

How to change this script so that I can connect remotely to my Mongodb running in docker-compose, from different machines (that are not connected to the same network/internet provider).

I want to allow all remote connections.

I don't care about security matters as it's just for practice purposes!


docker-compose.yaml script file:

```js
version: "3.8"
services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    container_name: mongodb
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    volumes:
      - data:/data
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=admin
      - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=admin
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    container_name: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD=admin
      - ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER=mongodb
volumes:
  data: {}

networks:
  default:
    name: mongodb_network
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue by migrating my data to Atlas cloud.mongodb.com

Answer update: 
 To provide more info as suggested by @nuhkoca, 
 
 This is the video tutorial to create a mongodb atlas: 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xrc7dIO_tXk&t=15s 
 And this is the link to the db from my resources file in my Springboot backend api: 
server.port=<Port_number>

spring.data.mongodb.uri=<Link_to_mongodb_atlas>

Comment: OP answered his own question and it overall looks good but more info would be useful, though.